# How to add Explicit Wait on Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I'm automating a task to export raw data from servicenow portal without API access. Hence, selenium comes to my mind.
I want the driver.execute_script to execute after it finds the element but i'm uncertain on how and where to put the explicit wait into the script. Currently I'm using driver.sleep()
Appreciate if anyone could provide insight, thanks in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def closeWebpage(driver):
    print("Closing webpage 5 secs ...")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
def loadWebpage(sec):
    #print("Loading webpage in "+ str(sec) +" secs ...")
    time.sleep(sec)

sn_web = "https://.service-now.com"


while True:
driver_action= ActionChains(driver)

    sn_js = """
    let output = '';
    let regex = new RegExp('macroponent*')
    for (let i of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
        if (regex.test(i.localName)) {
            output = i.localName;
        }
    }
    return document.querySelector(output).shadowRoot.querySelector('iframe');
    """
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName('i')[2].click();")
    except:
        
        driver.quit()
        loadWebpage(5)
        continue
    else:
         
        loadWebpage(1.5)

        #switch to iframe context
        incident_name_web_ele = driver.execute_script(sn_js)
        driver.switch_to.frame(incident_name_web_ele)
        
        loadWebpage(1.5)

        #hover over Export
        ele = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"context_item")
        driver_action.move_to_element(ele[len(ele)-1]).perform()

        #find CSV (.csv)
        find_csv_js = """
        let output = '';
        let regex = new RegExp('CSV')
        for (let i of document.getElementsByClassName('context_item')) {
            if (regex.test(i.innerHTML)) {
                i.click()
            }
        }
        """

        driver.execute_script(find_csv_js)
        loadWebpage(5)

        #click wait to export, could be enhance if there is no waiting needed
        driver.execute_script("g_export_schedule_dialog.waitForIt();")
        #loadWebpage(200)


        #download the excel
        driver.execute_script("g_poll_dialog.getResult();")
        loadWebpage(40)

        driver.quit()
        break
```